# How to handle Spring context shutdown when beans that are already destroyed are needed for the shutdown tasks

Tags: java, spring

I have a large and complex Spring application with many beans and services. During the shutdown process, one of the beans in particular (a cache service bean) is needed by several other beans to accomplish their shutdown tasks. The problem I'm running into is beans cannot access the required service, because it is in the process of being shutdown as well. I get an exception that a singleton instance of the cache service bean cannot be created while it's in the process of being destroyed.

One solution I've tried is creating a handler that implements `ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>`. This intercepts the context close event right as it's fired, before the beans are destroyed. In this handler I'm sending emails and calling the close/shutdown logic on the beans that in turn depend on the cache service. The problem seems to be that the shutdown process continues asynchronously while my logic is trying to execute and the required cache service bean is already destroyed by the time it's needed.

The only other solution that I can see is to implement a @PreDestroy method in the cache service itself which performs the shutdown tasks contained in the other beans. This is not optimal, since it tightly couples the cache service logic to other unrelated parts of the application.

Is there a way to "get in front" of the context close event to complete these tasks before any beans are destroyed? The application is running in a Tomcat container. Is there a way to intercept the stop signal from Tomcat and implement a custom handler where I can perform shutdown tasks, then manually call context.close() to begin the Spring shutdown process?